# GNU make: get and modify target name in prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a list of files like this:

```
/path1/file1.root
/path2/file2.root
...
/pathn/filen.root
```

that I want to use as a target. The only prerequisite to each target is a file which is in a `/path<>/log/` folder, has the same basename but different extension. So for example:

```
/path1/
  |-- file1.root
  '-- log/
        '-- file1.mac
/path2/
  |-- file2.root
  '-- log/
        '-- file1.mac
...

/pathn/
  |-- filen.root
  '-- log/
        '-- file1.mac
```

I can only find all these folders directly seeking my directory structure, all the paths are different and thus not reproducible a priori.

I want to produce the following rules:

```
/path1/file1.root : /path1/log/file1.mac
<tab>do_something

/path2/file2.root : /path2/log/file2.mac
<tab>do_something

...
```

And since automatic variables are not available in prerequisites this is not so easy to achieve (or at least in my limited understanding)

I managed to do this with the following:

```
define function
  $(1) : $$(dir $(1))log/$$(subst .root,.mac,$$(notdir $(1)))
  <tab>do_something
endef

$(foreach f,$(LIST),$(eval $(call function,$(f))))
```

But I don't know why it takes very long (~ 4min!) for make to read the Makefile (~ 50 folders in `LIST`)

I also tried something with static patterns but with no luck...

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: There is more than one way to do it, but... your `FILE` appears to contain paths to `.root` files. Wouldn't it be better to search for `.mac` files? If `foo.mac` exists, but `foo.root` does not exist, then your current makefile will not build `foo.root`.

Comment: The `do_something` instruction uses a `.mac` file to build the corresponding `.root` file, so as always I need to put the `.root` file as a target and the `.mac` one as the only prerequisite... I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Imagine you have `/path1/log/file1.mac`, but no `/path1/file1.root`. If you search for root files, you will find nothing corresponding to `file`. If you search for mac files, you can convert their names to "...root".

Comment: Ok now I got your point, I should have said that I look for _directories_ with `.root` files (because of other reasons they always exist), and then build up the `.root` file names from the path. This works because my directory structure is organised like this, all the `.root` file names are deducible from the path. Finding the `.root` files is not my issue, correctly writing the rules is. Can you elaborate your "There is more than one way to do it"?

Comment: Is it possible that the long duration comes from your script trying to find all files? How do you search for them? `$(wildcard )`? BTW why are you unhappy with your rules? Do you want it to be somehow "clearer"? I think your code is already quite short and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would start with a list of existing mac files and construct therefrom a list of desired root files, rather than a list of existing root files. But either way we will get a list of root files.

I think the best approach is a static pattern rule. We can use [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) to construct the prerequisite mac file:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(ROOTS): %.root: $$(dir $$*)log/$$(notdir $$*).mac
    do something with the target $@ and the prerequisite $<
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. For some reason it's a lot faster than the `eval` method.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be to use a build system that allows for dynamic dependencies.  Here's a make file that would work with [GoodMake](https://github.com/AmesCornish/GoodMake):

```
#? *.root
    # Find the corresponding .mac file
    mac=$(echo $1 | sed -E 's+(.*/)(.*).root+\1log/\2.mac+')

    # Flag the .mac file as a dependency
    $0 $mac  

    # Build the .root
    cat "something" >$1

#? !all
    $0 all-roots        # List all the roots
    $0 $(cat all-roots) # Make all the roots

#? all-roots
    # List all desired roots by finding all .mac files
    find -path '*/log/*.mac' | sed -E 's+(.*/)log/(.*).mac+\1\2.root+' >$1
```